# Readline keymapping C-/ not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, readline, inputrc

I have the following line in my `.inputrc` which does not appear to be working:

```
"\C-/": insert-comment
```

When I press `C-/` I expect the current line to be prefixed with the comment character (`#`) and executed, but when I press it nothing happens.

If I change the keymapping to something like `\C-t` then it works fine.

Why can't I use `C-/` as a keymapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The readline library follows the model of a physical terminal that could only transmit ASCII control characters and ANSI escape sequences. `C-/` is not an ASCII control character; the ASCII control characters are `c-@`, `C-a` .. `C-z`, `C-[`, `C-\`, `C-]`, `C-^`, `C-_`.

Comment: So what does this mean for Meta sequences like `M-#`? Or are they not subject to the same restrictions?

Comment: `Meta-#` is by convention an escape control character followed by `#` (or whatever character you want to "metafy"). The Readline library can also be configured to interpret the eight bit, if set, as a meta flag if the terminal (emulator) supports this. But this is very esoteric, since it restricts the input character set to seven bits.

Comment: Are there limitations on which characters can be "metafied"? `M-/` doesn't seem to work for me either.

Comment: For some reason I can't get the syntax `"\M-/"` to work in `.inputrc` either, but `"\e/": "your action here"` works. In my terminal emulator combining the Alt key with almost any key prepends an Esc to the key character. You can check by pressing `Ctrl-v` before the Alt-key combination, this prints the output like this: `^[/` (`Alt-/` used as an example).